# Openshift oc rsh Increase Timeout

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

If I `oc rsh <pod>`, the shell will timeout in a matter of seconds unless the shell is actively printing output.

How can I increase or eliminate the timeout of `oc rsh` ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like less of an issue with `oc rsh`, and more of an issue with how you're running your pods. If your pod exits, kubernetes will kill it and start a new one (that's just what it does). So, it sounds like you're running a short-lived script, and want to `oc rsh` to it for (I would assume) debugging purposes.

If that's the case, you should try `oc debug <pod>`, this will essentially give you the shell access you want, without the requirement for the pod to stay long running.

The other alternative could be something like `oc run`, which will basically just use the image you want, but you can override the `commands`. Something like

```
oc run -i -t busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- /bin/sh
```

(The `--restart=Never` basically ensures this is just a pod, and when you exit, it dies. If you omit it, it'll use a `DeploymentConfig` and when you exit, it'll just restart itself)

Answer (score 0):

In OCP4, TCP Streaming connections like oc rsh get closed after 60 seconds. You can increase the `timeout client` and `timeout server` in /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg and restart the haproxy service.

In OCP3.x < 3.10 try passing a kubeletArgument for the `streaming-connection-idle-timeout` parameter to /etc/origin/node/node-config.yaml like this:

```
kubeletArguments:
  streaming-connection-idle-timeout:
  - "10m"
```

In OCP 3.x >= 3.10 you'd need to add that kubeletArgument in the node configmaps, e.g.: oc -n openshift-node edit cm node-config-compute